# how run merge tables in postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have a script and I tried to make a custom function work. Is this possible to ?

A very frequently asked question here is how to do amerge table from a different schema function in Postgres? which is what ORACLE  calls MERGE INTO  ... USING 
and the standard supports as part of the MERGE operation in Postgres but somehow the PostgreSQL doesn't support it  and /or recognize the variable.  how would you do this? Consider the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CIDR_STAGING"."PR_MIG_STG_DATE_IN" (
v_Ret OUT int ) RETURNS integer
as $$

declare 
        v_ErrorCode             int;
        v_ErrorMsg              varchar(512);
        v_Module                varchar(32) = 'PR_MIG_STG_DATE_IN';

begin
   ----
   -- MERGING: STG_DATE_IN into SC_DATE_IN
   ----
   MERGE INTO cidrdba.sc_date_in prod
   USING (
           SELECT Receipt_Number,date_in, mig_filename,mig_insert_dt,mig_modified_dt
           FROM cidr_staging.STG_Date_In
           ORDER by mig_seq
           ) AS stg
   ON ( prod.receipt_number = stg.receipt_number )
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
   --   prod.Receipt_Number     = stg.Receipt_Number,
      prod.Date_In                      = stg.Date_In,
      prod.mig_filename                 = stg.mig_filename,
      --prod.mig_insert_dt                = stg.mig_insert_dt,
      --prod.mig_modified_dt              = stg.mig_modified_dt
      prod.mig_modified_dt              = current_timestamp
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
           (
                   prod.Receipt_Number,
                   prod.Date_In,
                   prod.mig_filename,
                   prod.mig_insert_dt,
                   prod.mig_modified_dt
           ) SELECT (
                   stg.Receipt_Number,
                   stg.Date_In,
                   stg.mig_filename,
                   current_timestamp,
                   --stg.mig_insert_dt,
                   null
                   --stg.mig_modified_dt
           )
   ;

   ----
        -- Set the return code to 0
        ----
        v_Ret := SQLCODE;

----
-- Exception error handler
----
exception
   when others then
           v_ErrorCode := SQLCODE;
                v_ErrorMsg  := SQLERRM;

                v_Ret       := v_ErrorCode;

                ----
                -- Commit the record into the ErrorLog
                ----
             PERFORM pr_write_error_log( sys_context('userenv','session_user'),
                                sys_context('userenv','host'), v_Module,
                                v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );

                ----
                -- Intentionally leaving the "commit" to application
                ----
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

ERROR:  "cidrdba.sc_date_in" is not a known variable
LINE 14:    MERGE INTO cidrdba.sc_date_in prod
                       ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 347

v/r,

Bach Nga

Comment: I'm confused, you seem to know MERGE INTO isn't supported in PostgreSQL but you are trying to use it anyway? Why aren't you using INSERT ... ON CONFLICT?

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) did you find `MERGE`?

Comment: I found "Merge" from this link, https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples

Comment: I have tried the INSERT ... ON CONFLICT and still not recognize the cidrdba_sc_g28, complained its not know variable.

even the simple insert below:
INSERT into cidrdba.sc_g28 prod
USING cidr_staging.stg_g28 stg 
ON CONFLICT (prod.receipt_number)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set --> with the rest of columns equal from prod = stg
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT the prod.columns, blah ... (SELECT stg.columns, blah )